# Add a file in a folder with bash

Tags: xml, bash

I have figured out how to remove bad files in my folders but I am wanting to know how to add certain named files to that folder.

I want to add something like address.xml

I have this and can remove the bad files.

```
    for addxml in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name address.xml); do
    rm -v $addxml
done
```

I am trying to learn how later down the code I can add a file from another folder no where near the folders that are being edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest checking out [`cp`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp) (to copy files/directories) or [`mv`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?mv) (to move files/directories)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an empty file, use `touch /<dir>/<filename.ext>` ([docs](http://www.howtogeek.com/74667/how-to-use-touch-to-create-empty-files-and-modify-timestamps/)). If you're trying to move a file from one place to another, use `mv <source> <target>` ([docs](http://ss64.com/bash/mv.html))

Answer (score 0):

vim address.xml   ...?

:wq

Are you creating a bash scrip to make files or you are in a command prompt and need to make a file?

Comment: I am running the bash script in a virtual environment with ubuntu installed.  I am learning bash and I have written everything in notepad++.I go into ubuntu and click "run in terminal" to execute bash on a few hundred files.

Answer (score 0):

> how later down the code I can add a file from another folder

```
OTHER_DIRECTORY=/home/CuriousGeorge/some/other/directory

for addxml in $(find $DIRECTORY/$directoryname -name address.xml); do
    mv $addxml $OTHER_DIRECTORY
done
```

Answer (score 0):

the question and the script does not match in the sense the script is looking for an existing file and the request states how to put a file (i.e. non existant file in to the location)

```
#!/bin/sh

FILECONTENT="something";
FILECONTENT=$FILECONTENT"something2";


for addxml in $(find . -name address.xml); do

if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo found
        echo   rm -v $addxml
else
        echo "putting content in $addxml"
        echo $FILECONTENT > $addxml
fi      
done

# OR CHANGE IT TO 
#FILECONTENT="/tmp/filecontent"
#cat $FILECONTENT > $addxml
```